# Wifi Problem in Ubuntu 14

Tags: wireless, virtualbox

I installed Ubuntu 14 on oracle virtual box but my wifi is not working. I went to additional driver in ubuntu but in my laptop it shows No additional driver available. I also tried to change the setting of virtualbox network part but the problem still persist.

Please help

Comment: I don't think you can get WiFi through VM. The VM should recognize a wired connection while your host computer computer should be connected however.

Comment: VM does not work in such manner as @Zacharee1 said. Guest VM's sees the Host adapters as just adapters as I recall despite what adapter you bridge/NAT to the guest VM.

Comment: @AzkerM To be fair, I haven't used a VM in a while, but I remember it adding two LAN adapters to the host machine, and not using the host adapters directly.

Comment: @Zacharee1 not to worry! I was agreeing to your point while adding my thoughts.. You're correct actually. I should've been more clearer. :D

Answer (score 0):

A virtual machine does not see the hardware of the host machine directly.

Your Ubuntu is not supposed to use the wireless interface. You do not need to install any wireless driers or connect to wireless networks from there.

If your host machine is connected to internet, your geust machine will see a wired virtual interface if you've set up the Virtualbox correctly.